# Probability of any family of being from a specific region.

Tags: probability

In a building there is 95 apartments means 95 family. Suppose there is a region called $X$.

For each family the probability of being of that region $X$ is $P(X) = 1/64$.

what is the probability of any family of that building (among 95) from that region?

Comment: Hint: it's easier to work backwards.  What's the probability that none of the families are from $X$?

Comment: Hint: Converse probability: 1-probability that none of any family of that building is from that region. **Argh!** Lulu is faster again.

Comment: @lulu I have understood the concept of backwards calculation. But what if I wanna calculate it forward way. Like if there is only 1 family in that building then the probability is 1/64. What if the family number is 2 or 3 or more ? I am not understanding in this way.

Comment: Well, you can do it that way but it's a lot more calculating. The probability that exactly $i$ of the families are from $X$ is $\binom {95}i\times \left(\frac {1}{64}\right)^i\times \left( \frac {63}{64}\right)^{95-i}$.  You need to compute these for $i=1$ to $i=95$ and sum these up.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be understood in two different ways:

1) At least one family is from that region. Then your probability is $1 - (\frac{63}{64})^{95}$, as  $(\frac{63}{64})^{95}$ is the probability that none are.

2) Exactly one family is from that region. Then the probability that every exact family is from that region is $\frac{1}{64}(\frac{63}{64})^{94}$ and there are $95$ families. So, your probability is $\frac{95}{64}(\frac{63}{64})^{94}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate how the probability of none are (1/64)^95.

Comment: @MahbuburRahman, you said, that the probability that a certain family if from that region is $\frac{1}{64}$, and I assumed, that you intended those events to be independent. And a joint probability of independent events is the product of their probabilities. In your case that's the product of $95$ copies of $1 - \frac{1}{64} = \frac{63}{64}$ for each of the families, which is ${(\frac{63}{64})}^{95}$. And ${(\frac{1}{64})}^{95}$ was a typo.